# Add an extra object to a javascript structure

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

So I have this structure that I get data from

```
data {
   one: one
   two: two
   additional {
      three: three
      four: four
   }
}
```

`additional` is inside `data`. I cannot edit this, because I get t form the back-end.

I also grab another structure like

```
data2 {
   one: one
   two: two         
   three: three
   four: four
}
```

I want those two structures to be the same, so I can parse them with the same piece of code. Is there a way to add an extra object in `data2` so it will become

```
data2 {
   one: one
   two: two
   additional2 {
      three: three
      four: four
   }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `data2[ 'additional2' ] = { three: three, four: four }; delete data2[ 'three' ]; delete data2[ 'four' ];`

Answer (score 0):

```
data2.additional2 = {
    three : 3,
    four : 4
};
```

Or dynamically...

```
data2.additional2 = {};
for (var prop in data.additional) {
    eval('data2.additional2.' + prop + ' = data.additional.' + prop + ';');
}
```

This is assuming that each property of additional is simple. You could do some more complex recursive checking and copying of properties. Or simply assign a whole object clone to it instead. Up to yourself :)

Answer (score -1):

There's a number of point to discuss here,

1. Your JSON is not in valid form. It should be

   data 2 = {one: 'one', two: 'two', additional: {foo: 'bar'}}
2. After that you can use `Object.assign` like so,

   ```
   Object.assign(data2, {additional: {foo: 'bar'}})
   ```

DONE!

Comment: I don't believe the data given is supposed to be JSON. It's just an abstract representation of a data structure. Also, they don't need `Object.assign`. `data2.additional = { ... }` would work fine.